How to draw random blobs underlaying the text

In this figure attached, I see a bunch of shapes/blobs as an underlay to the text. Does anyone know how can I make them myself? For example, I want to make the big blue one on the left side of the page.
The "blob" does not have to have a concrete shape with definite edges or corners. I just need it to be blobby enough to be something that works as a nice marketing flyer design.
I saw a few posts explaining how to make random ink blots but it did not seem to do the trick for me. I am also not sure how to overlay text on top of it.
Thank you in advance!

Maybe something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414740/improving-tikz-potatoes or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/647459/tikz-chain-of-open-sets-potatoes could be a starting point

You could just put fingerprints on a sheet of paper and scan it.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237557/coffee-and-wine-and-nicotine-stains-on-an-entire-document?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C86.3615

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, use Hobby shortcut]
\foreach \i in {0,...,100}{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{rnd}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\G}{rnd}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\B}{rnd}
\definecolor{randomcolor}{rgb}{\R,\G,\B}
\fill[randomcolor, opacity=0.5, closed, tension=20, shift={(-2+14*rnd,-20*rnd)}, scale=1.5] (0,0) .. (0,0.5+rnd) .. (0.5+rnd,0.5+rnd) .. (0.5+rnd,0);
}
\fill[blue!10, closed, tension=20] (-3,0) .. (0,2) .. (5,-5) .. (8,-8) .. (7,-18);
\end{tikzpicture}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}


